# What is plus.sandbox.google.com?

Tags: google

My client's website has had a couple of visits from the referrer — plus.sandbox.google.com. I looked it up and there isn't enough information available regarding this. Does anyone know what this url is?

Comment: I think it has something to do with https://plus.google.com/+CreativeSandbox though I am not sure why you would be seeing activity in your log files unless this is something that an employee is participating in that may be referring to a resource. What are they accessing? That may be a clue. It may be an image or video.

Comment: I & my client had similar thoughts (someone in Google's administration). My client blogs about positive thinking & there are a few quotes on the website. All visitors visited one of the latest post.

Comment: I did not dig into what Creative Sandbox was, but it looked like a user contribution vehicle of some sort centered around creativity (Duh...). The parent page looked a bit like Facebook so I assume there is some level of social media maybe with Google+. Some of this goes back to 2011 that I can see. Google seems to be branching out into other areas including hosting and it is getting harder to dissect access from Google IP address spaces. For example, people are using Google code to spider sites and do weird things. As well, sites Google hosts have gone rogue and have abused sites.

Answer (score 2):

`plus.sandbox.google.com` is apart of the Google Plus network. Generally sandbox is normally associated with testing. It's most likely a link that has just been added to someone's Google Plus only to be clicked moments during or after without Google scrapping the data. However normally Google will use: `http://plus.url.google.com/url?` as the referral.

If you take a look at:

- https://plus.google.com/+SimonHayter/
- https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+SimonHayter/

You will see that `plus.sandbox` is Google Plus... So if you see that as a referral you know its Google Plus.